# How to create a Python API and use it with React Native?

Tags: python, rest, http, react-native, server

I'm learning about basic back-end and server mechanics and how to connect it with the front end of an app. More specifically, I want to create a React Native app and connect it to a database using Python(simply because Python is easy to write and fast). From my research I've determined I'll need to make an API that communicates via HTTP with the server, then use the API with React Native. I'm still confused as to how the API works and how I can integrate it into my React Native front-end, or any front-end that's not Python-based for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to follow some online tutorial

And from my experiences, I think Flask is good choice for such case.

[This is basic flask tutorial provided by tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/index.htm)

Comment: Thank you! So this accomplishes the first part, but how do I get React Native to listen for and receive messages from the API or server?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a flask proxy, generate JSON endpoints then use fetch or axios to display this data in your react native app. You also have to be more specific next time.